# Is there a replacement for TAnimate in Delphi Prism?

Tags: .net, animation, media-player, avi, delphi-prism

I need something similar to TAnimate in Delphi win32 for Delphi Prism for .NET. So, I can animate or play AVI files. Do you know if there is any?

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For playing videos you can do two things:
Either embed a WIndows Media Player in your form and let this play the video. Infos here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383899(v=VS.90).aspx

The other way would also enables other animations: You use DirectX (in this case Direct2D). Infos here: http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/111181-adding-video-to-an-application/